# Is declared position of a script parameter ignored by PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I work on a script which is intended to be called by a third-party application. The application passes a bunch of parameters to a script but only a couple of them is needed in my case. All the parameters are passed by position. So I specified only the needed parameters with their positions in `Param()`:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=2)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$thirdParam=$(throw "Third parameter isn't specified"),
    [Parameter(Position=3)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$fourthParam=$(throw "Fourth parameter isn't specified"),
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [String[]]$redundantParams
)
$thirdParam
$fourthParam
```

Here is an invocation of the script and its output:

```
> .\Test1.ps1 1 2 3 4 5
1
2
```

Looks like `PowerShell` ignores the values of `Position` argument and binds the first and the second passed values to the `$thirdParam` and `$fourthParam` respectively. Even if a `Position` value is more than the actual number of passed parameter values it won't cause an error as if it were be ignored:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=1)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$secondParam=$(throw "Second parameter isn't specified"),
    [Parameter(Position=2)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$thirdParam=$(throw "Third parameter isn't specified"),
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [String[]]$redundantParams
)
$secondParam
$thirdParam
```

```
> .\Test1.ps1 1 2
1
2
```

In both cases `PowerShell v.4.0` is used:

```
> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.18144
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Why does `PowerShell` ignore `Position` argument? Is it possible to make `PowerShell` to take `Position` values into account in the case described above?

Comment: It doesn't ignore it, it applies it from lowest to highest - if `Position=3` is the lowest value declared, that will take the first positional parameter argument, `4` will take the next and so on

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Is it possible to discard several leading parameters passed to a script while binding them to variables with `Param()`?

Comment: I imagine you thought to just create some dummy parameters and then ignore them, but you're looking for a neater solution?

Comment: @CharlieJoynt Yeah. I prefer to keep my code clean =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you declare lower position number greater than "0" or different between numbers more than "1" ,position of  your lower position number will declare  "0" and once parameter closest bigger than lowest declare with "1" and next bigger declare with position "2" and so on . 
like this photo :

[image]

and you output will be :

```
7
8
```

Comment: i hope this help you . and sorry for my bad english language

Answer (score 2):

### UnboundArguments

If your script accepts *unbound* arguments (i.e. it doesn't specify `CmdletBinding`) then you can access both the *bound* and *unbound* arguments using the **$MyInvocation** built-in variable:

```
$MyInvocation.BoundParameters
$MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
```

You could dispense with the whole `param()` block and use `$MyInvocation.UnboundArguments` as a zero-indexed array to identify the positional arguments passed to the script:

```
$ThirdParam  = $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments[2]
$FourthParam = $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments[3]
```

Note that if you do have a `param()` block, then the positional arguments passed to the script are bound to these parameters, and thus to the `BoundParameters` object (aka **$PSBoundParameters**). All *remaining* arguments are added to the `UnboundArguments` list.

```
param(
  $one,
  $two)

Write-Debug "PSBoundParameters: $($PSBoundParameters.GetType().Name)"
$PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | Select Key,Value | Out-String

Write-Debug "MyInvocation.BoundParameters: $($MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetType().Name)"
$MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | Select Key,Value | Out-String

Write-Debug "MyInvocation.UnboundArguments: $($MyInvocation.UnboundArguments.GetType().Name)"
$MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
```

Comment: Does usage of `BoundParamters` and `UnboundArguments` have some advantages over usage of `Args`?

Comment: Seem to have lost my previous comment here. In short, no, you can use $Args. I guess I use $MyInvocation for other things so I am biased towards using that.